# jq - How to get list of values out in a list without keys

Tags: json, jq

.
sorry I am a newbe with jq, maybe I don't see the "forest because of to much trees". I have a json which looks simplified like:

```
{
  "a": "aaa",
  "b": "bbb",
  "types": "{2,4,5,10,13}",
  "c": "ccc"  
}
```

The wanted output from jq should be

```
2
4
5
10
13
```

I only get with "jq -r .types" the list out and have to parse it further then manually.
Is there a easy way to do all at once with jq single command?

Thanks in advance, Ralf

Answer (score 2):

Use `.types` to traverse to that key, then `scan` the string for consecutive digits with a regex. Use the `-r` flag to output raw text:

```bash
jq -r '.types | scan("\\d+")' input.json
```

```json
2
4
5
10
13
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-tUnwFiK6fm)

Just in case this isn't obvious: the string `{2,4,5,10,13}` is **not** a valid JSON-encoded object or array, so you cannot structurally "iterate" over the numbers. Use string functions (like `scan`) to handle it.

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfect !!! 

PS: I know that the json file is not valid, but it comes out of a ready made software, no way out ....